# sp_recompile does not recompile inline TVF. What alternatives are there other than using an ALTER statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following, I would expect the first `SELECT` of the new column `[Bit01]` to be successful however it is not. Is there any way of avoiding the use of the `ALTER` statement to get it to work?

I have not been anything to find anything that confirms or denies my findings on the relevant MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647(v=sql.110).aspx

```
-- Shell table
CREATE TABLE [tblRecords]
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
GO

-- Inline TVF
CREATE FUNCTION [ufnAllRecords]()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [tblRecords]
);
GO

-- Add a column
ALTER TABLE [tblRecords]
ADD [Bit01] BIT NULL;
GO

-- Recompile the function
EXECUTE sp_recompile N'ufnAllRecords';
GO

-- Attempt to select the new column
SELECT [Bit01]
FROM [ufnAllRecords]();
GO

-- Column does not exist and so it errors...
-- However it works after ALTER'ing it
ALTER FUNCTION [ufnAllRecords]()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [tblRecords]
);
GO

-- Now works
SELECT [Bit01]
FROM [ufnAllRecords]();
GO

-- Cleanup
DROP FUNCTION [ufnAllRecords]; 
GO
DROP TABLE [tblRecords];
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SELECT *` in production code is evil, for [a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select).

If you absolutely must do this, the procedure you're looking for is `sp_refreshsqlmodule`, which works much like the built in `sp_refreshview`, rather than `sp_recompile`.